# google glass wrong field of view

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm trying to obtain the horizontal field of view of google glass camera.
The getHorizontalViewAngle() function of Camera.Parameters return the value 54.8°, But by manual measurement I got the value of about 74°.
(The way I measure is by placing the camera in a center of circle with degrees marks, where the right side of the image shows 0°. The left size of the image shows 74°.)
Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what value do you get from getVerticalViewAngle()?

Comment: getVerticalViewAngle() gives 42.5°.
But I didn't check the value manually

Comment: Please file a bug in our public [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: ^^ Did that, I'll update here